# Removing virtual surfaces in view factor calculations

Tags: radiation

I've managed to get myself into a quandary. I am looking at (radiation) view factors and I subdivided my system to make the math easier. Now I'm having a hard time figuring how to put the system back together. So I know the view factors which hit the virtual surface "$a$" (which is a flat disk) separating surface 1 and 2 from 3 and 4.

So I know the view factors with the intermediary,

$$F=\left(\begin{array}{lllll}
    F_{1,1} & F_{1,2} & F_{1,a} & 0              & 0              \\
    F_{2,1} & F_{2,2} & F_{2,a} & 0              & 0              \\
    F_{a,1} & F_{a,2} & F_{a,a} & F_{a,3} & F_{a,4} \\
    0              & 0              & F_{3,a} & F_{3,3} & F_{3,4} \\
    0              & 0              & F_{4,a} & F_{4,3} & F_{4,4} \\
\end{array}\right)$$

And the areas

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{l}
    A_{1} \\
    A_{2} \\
    A_{a} \\
    A_{3} \\
    A_{4} \\
\end{array}\right)$$
But I can't think of how to get rid of the virtual surface to get,

$$F=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
    F_{1,1} & F_{1,2} & F_{1,3} & F_{1,4} \\
    F_{2,1} & F_{2,2} & F_{2,3} & F_{2,4} \\
    F_{3,1} & F_{3,2} & F_{3,3} & F_{3,4} \\
    F_{4,1} & F_{4,2} & F_{4,3} & F_{4,4} \\
\end{array}\right)$$

So I don't know the view factors in the upper right quadrant and in the lower left, any obviously these are related.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: 2015/07/14 17:03

Attached is a rough sketch. This is is a 2d slice of an axi-symmetric set of surfaces.
[image]

Edit: 2015/07/20 -

After struggling with this on and off for the past week, I'm still no farther along.

$F_{1,2}+F_{1,a}=1$

$\frac{A_{1} F_{1,2}}{A_{2}}+F_{2,2}+F_{2,a}=1$

$\frac{A_{a} F_{a3}}{A_{3}}+F_{3,3}+F_{3,4}=1$

$\frac{A_{3} F_{3,4}+A_{a} F_{a,4}}{A_{4}}=1$

$F_{1,2}+F_{1,3}+F_{1,4}=1$

$\frac{A_{1} F_{1,2}}{A_{2}}+F_{2,2}+F_{2,3}+F_{2,4}=1$

$\frac{A_{1} F_{1,3}}{A_{3}}+\frac{A_{2} F_{2,3}}{A_{3}}+F_{3,3}+F_{3,4}=1$

$\frac{A_{1} F_{1,4}+A_{2} F_{2,4}+A_{3} F_{3,4}}{A_{4}}=1$

I can solve the first four equations for their corresponding values but, I still can't come up with the cross terms because there are only three linearly independent equations. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can use reciprocity to relate the two quadrants, namely $A_i F_{ij} = A_j F_{ji}$. For non-concave surfaces, $F_{ii} = 0$, so $F_{aa} = 0$. In an enclosure, $\sum_j F_{ij} = 1$. Could you provide a figure?

Comment: If the four surfaces form an enclosure, then your rows must all add up to $1$.

Comment: Is there any way to use the $F_{a,*}$'s to find the terms that cross the virtual boundary?

Comment: Yes. Note that $F_{11} + F_{12} + F_{13} + F_{14} = 1 = F_{11} + F_{a1} + F_{a2} = 1 - F_{a3} - F_{a4}$ and so on.